# Concat multiple strings?

Tags: c

I have a line like the one below, but I need to concat slashes for directories, is there any way to safely concat multiple strings?

```
// Need to include \\ after windowsDir
FILE *dest = fopen(strcat(windowsDir, filename),"wb");
```

Comment: `'\\'` is a backslash, not a slash.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *buf = malloc(strlen(windowsDir) + 1 + strlen(filename) + 1); // len + \ + len + \0
sprintf(buf, "%s\\%s", windowsDir, filename);
FILE *dest = fopen(buf, "wb");
free(buf);
```

Comment: forgot the typecast before malloc.

Comment: @James: casting the return value from `malloc()` is not necessary in `C` and, in fact, is frowned upon because it may hide errors (failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`).

Comment: If I don't typecast in VSC++ I get an error even with stdlib.h included.

Comment: @James: are you compiling as `C` or `C++`? In `C`, `sizeof '#' == sizeof (int)`; in `C++` it very probably isn't. Try it: [C](http://codepad.org/N6m5n6hq) versus [C++](http://codepad.org/JA1DSd4b)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can configure the Microsoft compiler to be a C89 compiler. I don't use it though, so I can't help you with the proper way to set it up. If you're writing `C`, use a `C` compiler!

Comment: @James If you're using a .cpp file and submitting it to a C++ compiler then you are coding in C++ -- that is, the C++ standard, not the C standard, applies to your code. Since this question has a C tag and not a C++ tag, your comment about forgetting the cast is wrong and the fact that you get an error is irrelevant.

Comment: You **can** tell the VS compiler to compile as C - and you can name your files `*.c`!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there is enough space all around, this works

```
strcpy(buff, "C:\\foobar");
strcpy(value, "file.txt");
strcat(strcat(buff, "\\"), value);
/* buff now has "C:\\foobar\\file.txt" */
```

Comment: I would note that `sprintf` (or better, `snprintf`) is more general, more precise, and doesn't have to rescan the previous string for every append ... not a problem here, but `strcat` doesn't scale.

Comment: I hate [Schlemiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) too!

Comment: Oops ... s/precise/concise/ .... It's particularly bad when it's the library designer who is the schlemiel. strcat never ever should have been in the library, and strcpy should have been spec'ed to return a ptr to the NUL, not to the beginning of the string. The best solution at this point is to abandon this C language abomination, and yet we see one C homework question after another here.